# Convert value varchar into other datatype in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the Query

```
CASE SF.value
            WHEN '' THEN '9999999999'
            WHEN 'N/A' THEN '99999999'
            WHEN 'POA' THEN '999999999'
            WHEN 'Free' THEN -1
            ELSE IF(SF.value IS NULL,'9999999999',CAST(SF.value as DECIMAL))
        END as priceval,

    ///End Query
```

I have value in DB as

```
value(varchar)

    4
    4.5
    4.3
    6.6
```

after fetching from DB,

```
    PRINTING:
    var_dump($data);

    Output
    ---------
    string(1) "4"
    string(1) "5"
    string(1) "5"
    string(1) "7"
```

I Need get value in following order BY integer or Float or Decimal But value in order by

```
    string(1) "4"
    string(3) "4.3"
    string(3) "4.5"
    string(3) "6.6"

    (OR)

    int(1) "4"
    int(3) "4.3"
    int(3) "4.5"
    int(3) "6.6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `DECIMAL` without specifying precision, try `CAST(SF.value AS DECIMAL(10,1))`

Comment: Actually, when you cast to DECIMAL you will always receive strings as result from your query. You don't actually need to cast it to anything, and you'll receive it as a string anyways. There is absolutely no way to receive it as int "4.5", integers being integers.